# showing available product quanity in two different units in openerp / odoo

Tags: unit-testing, odoo, stock

i am working on odoo to implement for a liquor trading firm. Actually clent uses two different units e.g., unit(s) and case. Case size may vary. for example 1 Case = 12 or 18 or 24. In odoo if the default UOM is case then it shows available product quantity in decimal.
In any time if the available product quanity is 15 (for case size 12) how can it be possible to show the quantity as 1 case 3 unit(s) or 1.3 instead of showing as 1.25 case.
please help out of this situation.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a separate "Unit of Measure Category" for "Cases".

You can then define the "reference unit of measure for category" assuming 'one bottle'.
Then, add several more units into this category, like 12-case, 18-case and 24-case, each with a factor of 12, 18 and 24 respectively.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you mark the answer if it actually turned out to be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use _compute_qty against the uom object.

This requires at least 3 parameters (from uom id, qty, to uom id)

```
to_display = self.product_uom._compute_qty(self.product_id.uom_id.id, self.product_id.qty_available, self.product_uom.id, round=False)
```